# How to customize DevExpress grid SEO Paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm using dev express grid in my web application. Thinking to enable SEO paging for the grid, but the problem is I don't really like the auto generated url.

here is the example

```
http://www.sitename.com/results.aspx?seo[Name of the grid]=page3
```

how can I remove the seo, and basically change to the name I want. Example

```
http://www.sitename.com/results.aspx?products=page3
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/SEOFriendly.aspx online demo that describes how to accomplish this task.

Comment: you probably didn't read the question. They don't provide the solution for the problem above.